# File type and size limit works on localhost but not on webhost

Tags: php, file-upload

i am trying to limit max file upload size to 8mb if anything larger then it shows the message upload file under 8mb. i tested it on wamp server it seems to work if i upload 9mb image, but on my webhosting when i select larger image than 8mb the error message does not show even for image type.

here is my code

```
if($_FILES["file"]["size"] !='' && $_FILES["file"]["size"] > 8388608){
            $error[] = 'Selected image size is too large, upload under 8mb.';
        }elseif($_FILES["file"]["type"] !='' && !in_array($_FILES["file"]["type"], array("image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/pjpeg"))){
            $error[] = 'We accept only JPG / JPEG image format.';
        }
```

my webhost default limit is 8mb.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find the php.ini file on your webhosting and change the file upload limit such:

```
post_max_size=10M
upload_max_filesize=10M
```

Comment: I tried adding this and uploaded the php.ini in root dir but it does not change. i tried to change it using .htaccess the 500 internal page error shows. i the added it on config.php ini_set that also does not seems to work. :(